# Simple string concatenation updating array in Powershell

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, string-concatenation

I have an array of strings in Powershell. For each element I want to concatenate a constant string with the element and update the array at the corresponding index. The file I am importing is a list of non-whitespace string elements separated by line breaks.

The concatenation updating the array elements does not seem to take place.

```sh
$Constant = "somestring"
[String[]]$Strings = Get-Content ".\strings.txt"

foreach ($Element in $Strings) {
  $Element = "$Element$Constant"
}

$Strings
```

leads to the following output:

```
Element
Element
...
```

Following the hint of arrays being immutable in Powershell I tried creating a new array with the concatenated values. Same result.

What do I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you concatenate the values to the local variable `$Element` but this does not change the variable `$Strings`

here is my approach, saving the new values to `$ConcateStrings`. by returning the concatenated string and not assigning it to a local variable the variable `$ConcateStrings` will have all the new values

```
$Constant = "somestring"
$Strings = Get-Content ".\strings.txt"

$ConcateStrings = foreach ($Element in $Strings) {
    "$Element$Constant"
}

$ConcateStrings
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to show an alternative iterating the indices of the array

```
$Constant = "somestring"
$Strings = Get-Content ".\strings.txt"

for($i=0;$i -lt $Strings.count;$i++) {
  $Strings[$i] += $Constant
}

$Strings
```

Sample output with '.\strings.txt' containing one,two,three

```
onesomestring
twosomestring
threesomestring
```